Unable to get cURL command to run within a script with variables
I have what I thought was a simple script:
#!/bin/sh

URL=myserver:9443

myCmd="curl -sS -k -X 'POST' 'https://"
myCmd+=$URL
myCmd+="/SKLM/rest/v1/ckms/accessToken' "
myCmd+="-H 'accept: application/json' "
myCmd+="-H 'Accept-Language: en' "
myCmd+="-H 'Content-Type: application/json' "
myCmd+="-d '{ \"userid\": \"SKLMAdmin\", \"password\": \"XXX\" }'"
echo $myCmd

authTok=$($myCmd)

When I run it, I get this:
curl -sS -k -X 'POST' 'https://myserver:9443/SKLM/rest/v1/ckms/accessToken' -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'Accept-Language: en' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "userid": "SKLMAdmin", "password": "XXX" }'

curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: en'

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application

curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "SKLMAdmin",

curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "XXX"

curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 1:

}'

If I cut and paste what the echo outputs into the shell, the command works fine, but the line that executes it from within the script gives me that string of errors.
I assume I am violating some basic rule of using cURL within a script, but I cannot seem to figure it out. I need to make the URL a variable (and eventually the username and pwd), and that's where this seems to be breaking down.

See Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?

You have tagged bash but you are using sh, can you use bash instead?

See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 and in particular https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#I.27m_constructing_a_command_based_on_information_that_is_only_known_at_run_time.

sh is a link to bash on my system.
The other links are things I will check out, but the answer below got me going

Since you have tagged your question with bash I'm assuming you can use bash.  In which case you should use bash because it supports arrays.  Arrays a much better option for storing commands/command arguments:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

url=myserver:9443
uri='/SKLM/rest/v1/ckms/accessToken'
#data='{ \"userid\": \"SKLMAdmin\", \"password\": \"XXX\" }'
data=$(jo userid=SKLMAdmin password=XXX)

opts=(
    -sSk
    -X POST
    -H 'accept: application/json'
    -H 'Accept-Language: en'
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
    -d "$data"
)


authtok=$(curl "${opts[@]}" "${url}${uri}")

The array allows you to expand each individual option separately but as if they were quoted individually in order to prevent word splitting and other unwanted expansions.
"${opts[@]}"

Will expand to:
'-sSk' '-H' 'accept: application/json' '-H' 'Accept-Language: en' '-H' 'Content-Type: application/json' '-d' '{ \"userid\": \"SKLMAdmin\", \"password\": \"XXX\" }'


Thanks, this got me going!  The system I am on doesn't seem to have 'jo', but I was able to work around that manually.
